# How to recover deleted /etc/apt directory?

Tags: apt

Is it possible to recover /etc/apt directory without having to reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Comment: Yes, just restore it from your latest full backup.

Comment: You can not recover it doing a re-install either... there are passwords in there and ppa locations.  You would need a backup you made prior. Mind that you can get the files back to default by installing Ubuntu and mounting all your partitions without formatting them (including /), It will reset your system to default and you will need to reinstall all the software you installed yourself but all the configuration files stay on the system and will be used once that software is installed.